# add custom to mysql_fetch_assoc results array

Tags: php, arrays

is it possible to add custom data to the results so it can be used the same as the $results being returned?

ie i'd like to add a random number to the results;

```
$recordSet = mysql_query($sql,$this->conn);
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordSet)){
    $results[]=$row;
    /// add to results[] a custom field and value, ie 'random' = 1000
}
return $results;
```

and then i can use it the same as;

```
foreach($results as $res) $title = $res['title'], $random = $res['random'];
```

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordSet)){
    $row['random'] = rand() * 1000;
    $results[] = $row;    
}
```

Comment: hey n1313 - that doesn't get returned as part of the $results array. think i need somink like  'add to results array'; array( 'random' => '1000'), just looking again now

Comment: Unless your question is wrong or you're doing something weird, this is the correct answer. What's going astray?

Answer (score 0):

Add the random values in $result array

```
 
$row['random'] = $random_val # calculated random values 1000
```

Comment: adding it to the array is where im stuck!

Comment: You need to add this statement ( $row['random']=$random_val ) in your while loop ,before adding $row in $result Array